# Set a jquery date picker to select a particular date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 fields, DateFrom and DateTo, and a jquery date picker. If today is the 9th of February, I want the DateFrom field to show 01-Jan-2017 and the DateTo field to show 31-Jan-2017. How can I achieve that in this particular context ?

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlDocument").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceName + "/GetMIRReportValueAdmin",
            data: "{'Value':'" + $(this).val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                var data = msg.d;
                $('#infocontent-body').hide();
                $('#divParams').html(data);
                $('.date').datepicker({ constrainInput: true, duration: 'fast', gotoCurrent: true, dateFormat: 'd-M-yy', autoSize: true, showOn: 'focus',
                        changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: baseUrl + 'Styles/Images/datepicker.gif',
                        minDate: new Date(curryear, 1, 1), maxDate: '+15y', yearRange: '1990:2030',
                        beforeShow: function (input, inst) { $(this).blur(); }
                    });
                ProductList(); //If there is a product list
                StatusList(); //If there is a status list

                if ($("#ddlDocument").find('option').filter(':selected').attr("aosSubparameter") == "Early Withdrawal Report") {
                    GetLifeCompanyList(); //If there is a fund list
                    $("#ddllifecompany").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
                else FinancialProductList(); //If there is a financial product list
                //FundList(); //If there is a fund list
                CompanyList(); //If there is a company List example RA and nonRA
                if ($("#ddlDocument").find('option').filter(':selected').attr("aosSubparameter") == "Investment Statement" || $("#ddlDocument").find('option').filter(':selected').attr("aosSubparameter") == "Growth Report"
                  || $("#ddlDocument").find('option').filter(':selected').attr("aosSubparameter") == "Actuaries Report") {
                    ProductFundList(); //If there is a fund list
                    GetLifeCompanyList(); //If there is a fund list
                    $("#ddllifecompany").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert('Failed to load the requested data.');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
  var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
  var firstDay = new Date(y, m-1, 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(y, m-1 + 1, 0);
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", firstDay );
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", lastDay );
```